# JPMS and fat\uber executable JAR - how it works together?

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-11, maven-assembly-plugin

I wondered how does fat\uber jar works when using JDK > 8 (that is with JPMS in practice), along with executable jar.

I have two questions related to this topic:

**1. fat\uber jar creation\assembly process**

Each java module is typically one jar that holds `module-info.class` within the root entry.
I am working with maven and I am using maven assembly plugin to build the fat\uber jar (jar-with-dependencies ref descriptor).
If my application depends on many modular jars, how will all these jars lives together ? after all each jar's `module-info.class` will override the other jar's `module-info.class` file since all `module-info.class` are meant to be in the root entry... ?

(side mark: I have already tested it with [maven sample project](https://github.com/the-shultz/fat-jar-cross-JDK-versions) I have created, and found that the final fat jar holds the first encountered dependency's `module-info.class` **ONLY**. Using `-X` option also discovered that all other `module-info.class` files were skipped due to the existence of the first one...)

**2. Executable jar**

As known, executable jars can be run with `java -jar <jar-file-name.jar>`. When working with JDK 11 in this form - will my (fat) jar and all it's dependencies are run from the class-path and by that will be considered to be part of the unknown module ? or from the module-path ?

Comment: The simple answer is you can only have a single module-info.java apart from that if you create a ueber/fat-jar this breaks the whole module parts ....son in the end an module-info within a ueber/fat-jar is useless..

Comment: Working with fat, executable jar along with "java -jar" command is one of the most common practices in modern java applications, and you are saying that the whole JPMS (radical) change that java ecosystem has gone through is not relevant and applicable (from run-time perspective) for that common practice ? I must admit that this doesn't make any sense to my ears.

Comment: The module system has it's advantages but for fat jar apps the module system would makes only sense if you use it during the development (to force architectural constraints; cleaner module structures; better interfaces) but for the runtime it does not make sense from a technical point of view cause you can have only a single module-info per jar file ..apart from that that many single jar(fat) apps are not really jar's anymore for example spring-boot, quarkus etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the modules-info.class from the fat jar to get rid of the modularization metadata. This is an easy solution and now your fat jar will be executable.

```
zip -d FatJar.jar module-info.class
```