# Problems with apache.poi modules with Java 9+ : ResolutionException

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-module

A project that I'm working on is using poi.ooxml et poi in order to generate Excel files, but I'm having trouble with this part of the code since it doesn't seem to work with modules.

Using poi 3.3, or 3.5, I get the following error :

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module poi contains package
> org.apache.poi.util, module poi.ooxml exports package
> org.apache.poi.util to poi

Both of these jar are added to my modulepath, but the code can't run if both are in the modulepath because of this conflict.

The program use classes from both librairies, so I can't ignore one of them, as they can't replace each other. I tested with an empty project and I obtain the same error with both librairies in the module path.The poi jar files were obtained from [the official website](https://poi.apache.org/).

Is there a way to make them function together without using Maven or Gradle if possible ?
Thank you

Update : I merged both jar into one jar in order to prevent conflict and double module export, and it seems to have resolved my problem here.

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Apache POI, which pre-data Java 9 by over 5 years? http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.5-final - What happens when you upgrade to something vaguely modern and supported?

Comment: When i try to use the last version of apache POI, there are multiple modules that POI can't find. I tried to add them one by one but stopped after the fifth required module. 

I finally succeeded by merging poi and poi.ooxml into one JAR, and importing this jar instead of two separate JAR. Not the best solution, but it works for the moment.

I don't really have time to setup the upgrade of different modules like POI unfortunately, but it's on the list of things to do.

Comment: The needed modules are listed in the maven POM. POI 5.1.0 will list those as optional because of complains about the mass of dependencies and the problems with batik. So in the future it'll get a bit more complicated. Which modules did you miss, which weren't mentioned in the POM?

Comment: btw. JPMS and uber jars are a complicated topic [by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439038/jpms-and-fat-uber-executable-jar-how-it-works-together)

Comment: Didn't use the POM as the project didn't start as a Maven project and I only discovered Maven earlier this year. After importing the jar, there was multiple librairies missing : slf4j, xmlbeans, Sparse-Bit, etc...